# In java, What does such enum type compile to?

Tags: java, enums, java-8, enumeration

Below is the code that defines enum type.

```
enum Company{
    EBAY(30), PAYPAL(10), GOOGLE(15), YAHOO(20), ATT(25);
    private int value;

    private Company(int value){
        super(this.name()); 
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

that gets internally compiled to,

```
final class Company extends Enum<Company>{
    public final static Company EBAY = new Company(30);
    public final static Company PAYPAL = new Company(10);
    public final static Company GOOGLE = new Company(15);
    public final static Company YAHOO = new Company(20);
    public final static Company ATT = new Company(25);

    private int value;

    private Company(int value){
        super(this.name(),Enum.valueOf(Company.class, this.name()));
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functionally, yes. Literally no (you can't explicitly sub-class `Enum` for one thing). `enum(s)` have a `toString`. And your `enum` isn't valid code (you can't call `super()`) and `getValue` needs a return type.

```
enum Company{
    EBAY(30), PAYPAL(10), GOOGLE(15), YAHOO(20), ATT(25);
    private int value;

    private Company(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Company` can't explicitly subclass `class java.Lang.Enum`? I did not get u. How methods like `ordinal()` / `values()` are visible for objects of type `class Company` without subclassing?

Comment: @overexchange It does subclass `java.lang.Enum` you can confirm it by looking at the bytecode, however you can't subclass `java.lang.Enum` **yourself**; this simply won't compile as I explained. This extends is added by the compiler itself.

Comment: You can create a class which extends `Enum`, if you use an older compiler…

Answer (score 5):

If you remove call to `super` which is illegal and `this.name` as parameter to super is also illegal, compile it and ran javap on class, this is output:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap -p Company.class 
Compiled from "Company.java"
final class Company extends java.lang.Enum<Company> {
  public static final Company EBAY;
  public static final Company PAYPAL;
  public static final Company GOOGLE;
  public static final Company YAHOO;
  public static final Company ATT;
  private int value;
  private static final Company[] $VALUES;
  public static Company[] values();
  public static Company valueOf(java.lang.String);
  private Company(int);
  public int getValue();
  static {};
}
```

Here is bytecode for static, part of it

```
static {};
  flags: ACC_STATIC
  LineNumberTable:
    line 2: 0
    line 1: 75
  Code:
    stack=5, locals=0, args_size=0
       0: new           #4                  // class Company
       3: dup           
       4: ldc           #8                  // String EBAY
       6: iconst_0      
       7: bipush        30
       9: invokespecial #9                  // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
      12: putstatic     #10                 // Field EBAY:LCompany;
```

Comment: Strange. For "Company c1 = Company.EBAY;", where is the object creation?

Comment: @overexchange in `static{}`, if you want byte code can post it but not sure it makes sense.

Comment: But static{} will execute once when class is loaded and initialised. So does that block create objects for each member?

Comment: What about remaining fields?

Comment: @overexchange maybe it is best you run `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap -c -v -l -p Company.class`. Class attributes and field attributes will not match on hand-crafted class and proper enum.

Comment: If second chunk is bytecode , then what is the first chunk called? Compiled code?

Comment: @sofs1 if you remove illegal calls code will compile, that is mentioned at the beginning of the answer. Three and half years nobody had objections, do not know how it looks in Java 10 and do not care.

Answer (score 4):

Almost, your second snippet does represent well what is internally generated by the compiler (bytecode) however, it is not exactly the same.

A compiled enumeration will contains the `ACC_ENUM` flag which indicates that this class or its superclass is declared as an enumerated type and will be treated as such by the JVM.

Your second snippet would not (supposing it would compile) include this flag in the bytecode :

---

**ENUM**

```
final class Company extends java.lang.Enum<Company>
      minor version: 0
      major version: 52
      flags: ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER, ACC_ENUM
```

**CLASS**

```
final class Company
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
```

---

As for the rest of your logic (still supposing it would compile) it is right. Internally, an enumeration will be represented as a `final` class which extends `java.lang.Enum`. However, note that you can't directly extends `java.lang.Enum` yourself as this stuff is done by the compiler when creating an enumeration and would result in compilation error if you try to do it yourself.