# In java, what does such class type compile to?

Tags: java, reflection, compilation

Below is the code that defines `class` type:

```
package annotationtype;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args){


    }
}
```

that gets functionally compiled by `javac` to:

```
public class annotationtype.Example{
    public static Class<annotationtype.Example> class;
    {
        class = Class.forName("annotationtype.Example")
    }
    public annotationtype.Example(){}
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){}
}
```

My major focus is on the `Class<annotationtype.Example> class` static member variable in the above code. In addition, this member variable `Class<annotationtype.Example> class` is actually pointing to an object of type `class Class` that maintains meta data of `class Example` after `class Example` gets loaded into memory.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am not sure if you should see `class` literal as field since just like `this` it is `keyword` which we can also use even with primitive types like `int.class`. But if you are asking about *idea* of `class` then yes, it can be somehow treated as static field declared in class.

Comment: @Pshemo, it's probably because you can always do `Example.class`, i.e. referring a `static` member, called `class`. :)

Comment: Definitely no, `javac` does not compiles that way. Did you use an old decompiler to get that code?

Comment: I had been thru `javap -p` output.

Comment: @my-thoughts Please do not dump the literal meaning of `Example.class` in byte code. Please provide the functional translation as shown in  similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039980/in-java-what-does-such-enum-type-compile-to).

Comment: Nope, javap gives an output similar to what @dohaqatar7 shows below. There is no `.class` property. Adding a proper answer...

Answer (score 4):

Class literals are part of the language specification as noted in [JLS 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class.
>
> The type of C.class, where C is the name of a class, interface, or
> array type (§4.3), is Class<C>.
>
> The type of p.class, where p is the name of a primitive type (§4.2),
> is Class<B>, where B is the type of an expression of type p after
> boxing conversion (§5.1.7).
>
> The type of void.class (§8.4.5) is Class<Void>.

`javac` doesn't create a static `class` field for each class, but it will recognize a class literal expression and compile it correctly.

Take for example the class:

```
public class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Class<?> myClass = Hello.class;
                System.out.println("Hello, " + myClass);
        }
}
```

This compiles to (only relevant sections of bytecode included):

```
public class Hello   minor version: 0   major version: 52   flags:
 ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER 
Constant pool:    
#1 = Methodref          #11.#20        // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V    
#2 = Class              #21            // Hello
......
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
     0: ldc           #2                  // class Hello
     2: astore_1
```

You can see that `javac` has put a reference to the Hello class in the constant pool and then loaded that constant when I refer to it in `main`.

Comment: @overexchange, that's the answer you want, +1.

Comment: You should quote the relevant section of the JLS in your answer.

Comment: @uraimo So, I am not suppose to go by the syntax of `Hello.class`, interpreting that `class` is a member of `class Hello`. I am suppose to interpret as, `javac` doing under the hood job of interpreting `Hello.class` syntax as special syntax and provide corresponding byte code to create object of type `class Class` and  `myClass ` points to that object. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. You see that `#2 = Class              #21            // Hello` in the constant pool of the Hello class? That's the result of the work done by `javac`, that adds a class constant to the constant pool of the .class file and use it with the `ldc #2` bytecode ( ldc=load constant from constantpool).

Comment: @uraimo 1) Is it the same constant pool where `class String` literals are stored?  2) I did not get this: "that adds a class constant to the constant pool". what is class constant?

Comment: 1) If you mean interned Strings, no, that's the String Pool, if you mean string literals loaded from the .class file javac produces, yes. 2) I was referring to that `#2 = Class` you see above,  learn more about the Constant Pool from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209952/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-java-constant-pool

Comment: @uraimo within main method, is that byte equivalent to,  'myClass = Class.forName("Hello");'?

Comment: @uraimo It isn't, the class literal expression is evaluated into a Class reference by the compiler. Class.forName() isn't evaluated until runtime.

Comment: @Dev am totally confused. Assume, I keep `main()` method empty in your answer and compile `Hello.java`. When is member `Class class` come into existence that gets pointed to an object that has meta data about `Hello`? Because when I type `Hello.` in eclipse, `class` member is already visible.

Comment: @overexchange The expression `Hello.class` is not a reference to a `class` member (which doesn't exist) it is a ***literal*** reference to the class `Hello`.  The expression is evaluated at compile time just all all other literals.

Answer (score 0):

If by "functionally compiled" you mean that the `class` "field" is available to you without you explicitly declaring it, then you are correct. Of course, `class` isn't a field, it's a  class literal  in the java language.

Furthermore, if we compile `javac Example.java` then disasemble `javap -c Example` we are left with this:

```
Compiled from "Example.java"
public class Example {
  public Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

note that there is no reference to `class` in this dissembled code. On the other hand, the default constructor `Example()` does magically appear so, it is fair to say that

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

compiles to

```
public class Example {
    public Example(){}
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no member by name `class` in disassembled code, why does java allow you to say `Example.class`?

Comment: @overexchange because class literals are part of the language spec [JLS 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)