# Why do Java Enums uses more memory than Interfaces?

Tags: java, javacompiler

I tested class, enum, interface these 3 ways to encapsulate constant String.

```
   public class Company {
        public final static String CAPITAL_ONE = "Capital_One";
    }
    public interface ICompany {
        public final static String CAPITAL_ONE = "Capital_One";
    }
    public enum ECompany {
        CAPITAL_ONE
    }
```

After compile, they generated 330 bytes, 181 bytes and 818 bytes bytecode which means interface ICompany will cost less memory when loaded into jvm. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe because those are not equivalent data structures?

Comment: The interface just needs to have a field name, type, and value. The enum needs to store multiple different method implementations (`values()` and `valueOf(String)`, as well as static initialization) in addition to the constant value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `javap` utility to examine the 3 ".class" files and compare the outputs.  For example:

```
$ javap -c Company.class
```

The short answer is there are some standard methods (`values()`, `valueOf(String)`, `toString()`) that the `enum` class has to implement, but the other classes don't have to.

Having said that, the size of a ".class" file is not necessarily an accurate predictor of the memory used when a class has been loaded and JIT compiled.

Answer (score 0):

A single class file defines either a class or interface. Looking at the structure (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html):

```
    ClassFile {
    u4             magic;
    u2             minor_version;
    u2             major_version;
    u2             constant_pool_count;
    cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
    u2             access_flags;
    u2             this_class;
    u2             super_class;
    u2             interfaces_count;
    u2             interfaces[interfaces_count];
    u2             fields_count;
    field_info     fields[fields_count];
    u2             methods_count;
    method_info    methods[methods_count];
    u2             attributes_count;
    attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
    }
```

An Enum is a class, and if you look what it compiles to, you can see why there is necessary overhead (see here: [In java, What does such enum type compile to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039980/in-java-what-does-such-enum-type-compile-to)). An interface is an abstract type, which is really just a set of operations and constants that a class must conform to.

ICompany.class:

```
����4   
CAPITAL_ONELjava/lang/String;
ConstantValue
SourceFile
ICompany.javaICompanyjava/lang/ObjectCapital_One
```

ECompany.class:

```
����4(  


!

"
"   #$CAPITAL_ONE
LECompany;$VALUES[LECompany;values
()[LECompany;CodeLineNumberTablevalueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)LECompany;<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V   Signature()V<clinit>Ljava/lang/Enum<LECompany;>;
SourceFile
ECompany.java
%&ECompany'java/lang/Enumclone()Ljava/lang/Object;5(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;@1
@
    "
����    "
*���*+��7�Y��   �Y� S��
```

From the class files, you can see that the interface in the example does not have much added to it in terms of methods or flags, hence the smaller size.